# What do those constructs in gradle.build really mean?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have created a basic gradle build. My build scripts contain constructs such as:

```
subprojects {
  group = 'tld.example'
  version = '0.1'
}
```

I deciphered this one: Build script is delegating all calls to [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) object, and [subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#subprojects%28org.gradle.api.Action%29) is just a method defined on that object, which accepts a [Closure](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_closures).

Easy enough. But what does this one mean?

```
model {
  components {
    foo(NativeLibrarySpec) {
      sources {
        cpp {
          source {
            srcDir "src"
            include "**/*.cpp"
          }
          exportedHeaders {
            srcDirs "${rootDir}/include"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fair enough, it is bit longer than the previous snippet, so namely:

- I have a bit of trouble to follow the context, while going all the way down from model to e.g. source
- I am quite certain there is no foo method/property defined on anything, so what am I actually calling/doing by saying foo(NativeLibrarySpec)? Wild guess would be that groovy has some [PHP-like magic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), which will handle this?

Comment: @il_raffa: Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` defines a library with that name.

You can look it up [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html#N1607B).

Comment: Yes, foo defines library with the same name, that is understood. The question is, what exactly does that mean from groovy's perspective (i.e. what function on which object is called, etc.)